# performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: not working after force quit (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have an app and everything works properly. However, when I force the app to quit (multitask -> quit app), then the restart doesn't work properly. Everytime when I press a button it DOES display the next View, but `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` doesn't get executed (because NSLog doesn't display).

This is a problem because I sent information with `prepareForSegue:sender:`. So without these methods, the app doesn't work properly anymore.

I tested it on:

Simulator:

- 3,5 and 4 inch
- iOS 6 and 7

iPhone:

- iPhone 4, 4S and 5
- iOS 6 and 7

iPad:

- iPad 2
- iOS 6 and 7

**EDIT**

Okay, so the code is below.

```c
// Gets executed when the user presses the button
- (IBAction)loginButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MyModalViewSegue" sender:sender];
}

// This will get called too before the view appears
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MyModalViewSegue"]) {
        // Get destination view
        ModalViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Set the delegate and password mode
        vc.mode = @"triple";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, without code it's hard to figure out what's wrong...

Comment: There are no `NSLog` statements. Maybe that's why you don't see them?

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but I removed the NSLog statements for readability. But what I noticed is that clicking the button after relaunch does give me the next view, but does not trigger the loginButton: method.